# ActiveX control versioning and signing

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, add-on, cab

I made an ActiveX control packaged as cab and put it in my web server.
The cab was digitally signed with a dummy signature.
On the client machine, in "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files" I could find the dll and osd files that were extracted from the cab.
Now I bought a real certificate and signed the cab on the server with it.
When I logged in as a client, after setting some secutity settings, I expected to see a prompt for downloading an ActiveX control with my name as publisher. That didn't happen. Then I went to "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files", deleted the dll and osd file that were extracted from the cab, logged in as client again and then I did see what I was expecting to see: a prompt for downloading an ActiveX control with my name as publisher.
My question is: why couldn't I see the signature in the first login? sure, the dll and osd files were already there, and the dll had the same version, but doesn't the fact that the cab was signed with a new signature and timestamped mean anything? and another question - if the dll inside the cab had a newer version number than the one in "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files", would it then be overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the version number is being detected to decide whether to redownload the control. If the version number of CAB is newer than that of the local copy, it will overwrite the one in "C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files".

Comment: What determines the cab version? How can I see it? Is it identical to the version of the dll inside? Is it the version specified in the code base property of the object tag in the html?

Comment: By the way, I see that when I change the version in the codebase property to "-1,-1,-1,-1" or any version that is greater than the version of the dll in the client machine, the prompt comes up on every refresh of the client's page. When the version in the codebase property is equal or lower, the cab is not downloaded and there's no prompt. So I want to see if I get the workflow: IE compares the version of the dll in the client's machine to the version specified in the html page. If client's version is not updated, the cab is downloaded from the server. Else, the client's dll is used. Correct?